# Find command with -mmin not working as expected

Tags: find, aix

In our production servers(AIX)there are multiple API calls which made every micro seconds and those API call details will be appended in an log called **ins.log**. On the other hand, we are using this data from the log to publish in a dash board so we will take the log file which got updated in the last 5 minutes using the command:

```
find . -type f -name ins.log -mmin -5
```

Without `-mmin`, the command finds the file, and you could see the modification time of the file is recent:

```
$ date
Tue Aug 29 18:34:54 +08 2023
$ find . -type f -name ins.log | xargs ls -l
-rw-r--r--    1 123456  123grp        74356 Aug 29 18:34 ./ins.log
```

But when I add `-mmin` it doesn't find the file.

```
$ date
Tue Aug 29 18:35:41 +08 2023
$ find . -type f -name ins.log -mmin -60
```

For example

- if the ins.log get updated at 3:15 and the system date is 3:15 and the script runs at 3:15 then the ins.log which updated at 3:15 not coming in the output

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for [`find -mmin` on AIX](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=f-find-command#find__a133z92520) describes this as an expected effect:

> Files that are modified after the `find` command start time are not taken into account

So because you are (very) frequently updating the file, such that it's updated after you started your `find` command, it will be omitted from the list.

The fix is described in the same notes paragraph:

> when the `find` command is used within the unary `NOT` operator […], the files that are modified after the command start time are displayed until the value of `n`.

Following this detail, you should simply need to invert the test so that you can use `!`:

```
find . -type f -name 'ins.log' ! -mmin +59
```